# Change \parskip only inside enumerate & itemize environment

Tags: latex, markup

Is there any way that I can change `\parskip` to a different value inside certain environments, namely `enumerate` and `itemize`.

I want to have space between paragraphs (`\setlength{\parskip}{1em plus 1pt minus 1pt}`), but not inside itemize or enumerate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can; but you will have to alter either the `enumerate` and `itemize` environments from your class file (by copying them and adding your `\parskip`), or by redefining `\@listi`, which works for all lists:

```
\makeatletter

\def\@listi{%
  % default settings for base LaTeX classes at 10pt:
  \parsep 4pt plus 2pt minus 1pt
  \topsep 8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
  \itemsep 4pt plus 2pt minus 1pt
  % your settings:
  \parskip 1em plus 1pt minus 1pt
}

\makeatother
```

If you want different settings at nested list levels, change `\@listii`, `\@listiii` etc.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping there would be something easier. Thank you

Comment: If you're fealing adventurous, you could try `\expandafter\def\expandafter\@listi\expandafter{\@listi \parsep 1em plus 1pt minus 1pt}` That way, you don't need to copy the existing settings (`\expandafter` will do that for you).

Answer (score 18):

If you use the `enumitem` package, you can say in your preamble

```
\setlist[itemize]{parsep=0pt}
\setlist[enumerate]{parsep=0pt}
```

to get what you want. `enumitem` allows for doing much more list customization, see its documentation for details.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the most helpful answer for me. +1.

Comment: That's a nice package. Unfortunately, [it conflicts with `beamer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer).

Answer (score 6):

you can also use:

```
begin{itemize} \itemsep -5pt
\item foo
\item bar
\end{itemize}
```

and that will only affect the current list.

Answer (score 0):

The following addition to the preamble updates `enumerate` to make the suggested change:

```
\let\oldenumerate\enumerate% Keep a copy of \enumerate (or \begin{enumerate})
\let\endoldenumerate\endenumerate% Keep a copy of \endenumerate (or \end{enumerate})
\renewenvironment{enumerate}
  {\begin{oldenumerate}
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}% Adjust \parskip to suit your needs
  {\end{oldenumerate}}
```

Here is a complete minimal example showing the adjustment when setting `\parskip` to `0pt`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First line

    Second line
\end{enumerate}

\let\oldenumerate\enumerate
\let\endoldenumerate\endenumerate
\renewenvironment{enumerate}
  {\begin{oldenumerate}
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
  {\end{oldenumerate}}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First line

    Second line
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

One would do exactly the same for `itemize`.