# LaTeX: blank line in centered enviroment

Tags: latex

I'm working on TeXmaker for the first time and I don't understand how to leave a blanket line inside a centered enviroment. If I write

```
1 Hello,\\
2
3 world!
```

Also in the .dvi file there is a blank line between Hello and world. But the code

```
1 \begin{center}
2 Hello,\\
3
4 world!
5 \end{center}
```

just ignores the third line and gives in output:

Hello,
world!

centered, of course. How can I put a blank line between the two words? I know I can simply close the center tag when I need a blank line, but having another alternative would be great :)

Comment: What you have done was breaking line hard (`\\`) and starting new paragraph (free line). I recommend you to use `\\` command only when you need to a you know what to do. In other cases use free line to start new paragraph, or `\par` command (first way looks better in source code) or `\linebreak` to break long line in one paragraph.

Comment: Uhm,that solution is similar to the ~\\, isn't it? I actually can't find a good guide containing this solutions, so thank you for you advices

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using a hard space (i.e., a tilde) and a linebreak in the blank line.

```
1 \begin{center}
2 Hello,\\
3 ~\\
4 world!
5 \end{center}
```

Comment: Another way to achieve that is `Hello\\[2ex] World!` (1ex is height of glyph - letter - x. You can use any unit used in typography -cm, mm, in, pt,...-) Or `\vspace{2ex}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changing `parskip` only in certain environments might be what you want:

[Change \parskip only inside enumerate & itemize environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180567/change-parskip-only-inside-enumerate-itemize-environment)